# Insert records into SQL Server 2012 Using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert records into SQL Server 2012 using C#.

I've done it in this way, but the problem is the insert record statement does not add the record at the end of the table.

It was working correctly, but sometimes (each time is different) it is inserting in the middle of the records and sometimes work correctly. it is not clear for me why this is happening.[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr9zT.jpg)

Any soultion ?

```
public partial class AddDoc : System.Web.UI.Page
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\BAKRSQL; Database=Diseases Prediction Sys;Integrated Security=True");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    string com = "select top 1 DId From Doctor ORDER BY DId Desc;";
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(com, con);
    object count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (count != null)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(count);
        i++;
        TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "101";
    }
    con.Close();
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs) 
{    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =@"Data Source=.\BAKRSQL; Database=Diseases Prediction Sys;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Doctor(DId,Name,Address,Mobile) values (@DId,@Name,@Address,@Mobile);", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DId", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
}
}
```

Comment: You think that you use Visual Studio 2010 (btw,. terribly outdated) makes a difference? Really? If not - why tag it with the IDE? You also do not tag it with your breakfast.

Comment: If you use SQLS2012 why tag SQLS2008?

Comment: Please,. tag your question correcty. And please do not whine about your mistakes - learn from them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because I am using Local SQL2008 and remote SQL2012. I want to know if there is difference between it using this string com = "select top 1 DId From Doctor ORDER BY DId Desc;";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables have no order. Simple. You insert with ID - but that is just a field.

You want order, you select with order statement.

Fundamental in every SQL Databsae ever written.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server maintains a relational model (i.e. based on the set theory). Therefore as is, there is no addition at the end of the table as such. While displaying records you may get a certain order, which can be changed using [Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) or [Rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189798.aspx) functions, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a physically ordered table, you need to create a `clustered index` on the field that you want the ordering to go by. You need to do this on the SQL server side - nothing to do with your C# code.